# Two queries look identical but behave differently

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a MySQL course on Udemy and I have hit an issue which I cannot explain:

Query 1 (mine) returns nothing and just shows an 'OK' in the Action Output panel.
Query 2 (the solution offered on the course) does return the value required.

Problem: they look exactly the same to me - if, as I have been told, MySQL is not case sensitive.

Really grateful if someone could help explain this or make me look ridiculous by pointing out an error I have missed despite having looked at this for too long.

Yours, R

Query 1:

```
delimiter $$
create function emp_info_rom(p_first_name varchar(255), p_last_name varchar(255)) returns decimal(10,2)
deterministic no sql reads sql data
begin
declare v_max_from_date date;
declare v_salary decimal (10,2);
   
select max(from_date)

into v_max_from_date
from
    employees e
    join salaries s on e.emp_no = s.emp_no
    where e.first_name = p_first_name and e.last_name = p_last_name;

select s salary
into v_salary
from
    employees e
    join salaries s on e.emp_no = s.emp_no
    where e.first_name = p_first_name 
        and e.last_name = p_last_name 
        and s.from_date = v_max_from_date;

Return v_salary;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Query 2:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION emp_info(p_first_name varchar(255), p_last_name varchar(255)) RETURNS   decimal(10,2)
DETERMINISTIC NO SQL READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_max_from_date date;
    DECLARE v_salary decimal(10,2);
SELECT
       MAX(from_date)
INTO v_max_from_date FROM
       employees e
        JOIN
        salaries s ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no
WHERE
    e.first_name = p_first_name
        AND e.last_name = p_last_name;
SELECT
    s.salary
INTO v_salary FROM
    employees e
        JOIN
    salaries s ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no
WHERE
        e.first_name = p_first_name
        AND e.last_name = p_last_name
        AND s.from_date = v_max_from_date;
RETURN v_salary;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

There must be a difference somewhere but I cannot see it :o/

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
select s salary into v_salary
```

in the second query.  Unless you have a column named `s`, this should return a syntax error.

That said, you could simplify this you using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SET v_salary = (SELECT s.salary
                FROM employees e JOIN
                     salaries s
                     ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no
                WHERE e.first_name = p_first_name AND e.last_name = p_last_name
                ORDER BY s.from_date DESC
                LIMIT 1
               );
```

I'm surprised the answer for the course doesn't use something like this.  Repeating the `JOIN` and filtering is not only redundant, but it is prone to error and less performant.

Comment: I was bound to be something ridiculous like this... feel a bit sheepish here. Many thanks for taking the time. Regarding the other approach to structure the query, the focus on this chapter was on functions, so perhaps there were trying to avoid confusing our poor souls furthers. Whishing you a nice day.  Yours, R

Comment: @thierryr . . . I would have voted to close the question, but there seemed like a better way to write the query -- which is why I provided an answer.